# Is it best practice to have all app Requests in AFNetworking 2 singleton?

Tags: ios, web-services, networking, ios7, afnetworking-2

Im using a AFHTTPSessionManager subclass as a Singleton, like most tutorials recommend to do. 
But Im coding also in that singleton absolutely ALL the app requests from login to fetching users details and posting to walls etc.. everything using blocks, so methods can be called from other locations in the app using this singleton.

So my client .m file is getting very big. Im doing this just to keep using the same AF Client singleton all across the app.

I was thinking, each model class should have its own networking methods. Ex. User class should have its own methods to update name, birthday, etc.. but then what happened to the singleton ?

So whats the best practice to use a singleton or to have requests be managed by each model class?